# How to set page title for forum's Active and Unanswered tabs in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes, routes

I have to set up forums in Drupal 7. I want to set page title, meta keywords and meta description for forum tabs like

> Active Forums and Unanswered Topics for forum.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem by setting custom page title in our theme's template.php file.

i have used **bartic theme** so in my function in template.php file is as follows

```
 function bartik_process_page(&$variables) { 
    $path = $_GET['q'];
    if (strpos($path,'forum/active') !== false)
       {
        $variables['head_title'] =  drupal_set_title('Your_Page Title');
       } 
   }



 function bartik_preprocess_html(&$variables) { 
 global $theme_path;

// Add conditional CSS for IE7 and below.
  drupal_add_css($theme_path . '/css/ie.css', array('group' => CSS_THEME, 'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lte IE 7', '!IE' => FALSE), 'preprocess' => FALSE));

 $variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', array(drupal_get_title(), variable_get('site_name'), variable_get('site_slogan'))); 
  }
```